# Codename one, Android theme.res seems to be broken

Tags: codenameone

My theme.res file was working before i started adding png images. Now it doesn't work when i choose "**Override in Platform**" for Android Phones.

But on other platforms(Android Phones&Tablets, IOS Win etc) i can see the preview of the form design on the right of the GUI builder.

I test using my note 4, Build succeeds but when i try to install the app i get this error message

`Java.lang.IllegalArgument.Exception: Theme entry for Main.bg.Image could not be found`

This is VERY UNCOOL because i am almost done with the app, I was just left with the UI design.

[EDIT]

Now i am also getting this error

```
`Error Loadin File : java.io.EOFEXCeption`
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the designer tool (resource editor) uncheck `File->XML Team Mode` then try to open the res file.

Comment: fixed now broken again, WHATS WRONG WITH THIS theme.res file, I am really getting frustrated. I have to call your guys support or something

Comment: Try running the designer from command line and look if you can see an exception.

Comment: i am using windows, luckily i also us GIT, So i rolled back and redid everything from my last commit.